# Omniauth returns a 401 unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I want to implement login and register with Twitter omniauth on my site. I have followd [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised?view=asciicast), but when I click the "Log in with twitter" link, I receive a `401 Unauthorized`. When I look in the log I see this:

```
GET "/users/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=xxx&oauth_verifier=xxx
omniauth: (twitter) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#twitter as HTML
  Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"xxx", "oauth_verifier"=>"xxx"}
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = 'twitter' AND "users"."uid" = '9999' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 13ms
```

When I look in the omniauth controller, it has found a user, but it seems to fail on the `sign_in_and_redirect user` line.

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      # it reaches this
      flash.notice = I18n.t('.devise.omniauth_callbacks.success')
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, notice: I18n.t('.devise.omniauth_callbacks.failure')
    end
  end
  alias_method :twitter, :all
end
```

In `config/devise.rb` I have added the key and secret like this:

```
config.omniauth :twitter, ENV.fetch("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"), ENV.fetch("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET")
```

And then the actual values are stored in `.rvmrc` like this:

```
export TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY=xxx
export TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET=xxx
```

This probably means that it tries to login the found user but fails on some validation right? But I removed all validations in the user model to check what happens, and I still get this error. Anyone any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Check your `ApplicationController` for a `before_filter` or `before_action` that involves a `current_user`. You are probably requiring authentication in your `OmniauthCallbacksController` when you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be `strong parameters`. I would suggest you get all you want from `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` into some variables instead of directly using in for creation or find.

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
 uid = auth[:uid]
 provider = auth[:provider]

 User.where(provider: provider, uid: uid).first
end
```

This should fix the unauthorized error.

Comment: You were right, I forgot to add ``provider`` and ``uid`` to the permitted devise sign_up parameters, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue ("Omniauth returns a 401 unauthorized") but the cause was different.

In my `User#from_omniauth` I do this

```
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create
```

which means that it creates a new user if one was not already there. Also, my `User` is `devise :confirmable`, and unconfirmed User can not sign in. That is why the authentication failed.

There would have been an error message stating this, but in the view that I was redirected to there was no:

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

So, the solution was to add this to the method in the CallbacksController:

```
def github
  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

  if @user.persisted?
    @user.skip_confirmation!
    @user.save
  #...
```

skip_confirmation is a devise method and it does this on the User:

```
self.confirmed_at = Time.now.utc
```

so, alternatively this could have been done in `User.from_omniauth`

Comment: I also need to remove `devise :confirmable` to make it work. Thanks @bosskovic